# Transferring parsed strings to sql server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, parsing

I have this program  that is feeding me data. I take this data (string) and parse it so that the different fields can go into the respective db table column. I can parse the string but I can't find the right function or way to send them to the db. This is my second time working with sql server or database in general. I have done inserts this way

`MyCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        MyCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TimeStampTable(ID, TimeStamp) VALUES ('24', 'sep 13, 2009')";`

From what I know, CommandType only allows either text or a stored procedure. In this case, I would want to insert the string that is being parsed.

```
string teststring = dtString;
string[] result = teststring.Split(',', ' ', ':', '=');
Console.WriteLine("The parsed string looks like this:");
foreach (string word in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

This is my code that parses my incoming string. So I receive name address zip state, etc. I would like for name to go to col1, address to go to col2, etc. I think the ideal way to do this would be to convert my loop to something like this

```
foreach (string word in result)
{
    SqlDatasource.InsertCommand=Insert into Tablename col1 col2 col3(word);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your question directly, but there are many different ways that you could go about performing the same thing (I will list some at the end)

```
String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLENAME (Col1, Col2, Col3...) VALUES (";
//This is also assuming that your data is in the same order as the columns
int isFirstLoop = true
foreach(string word in result)
{
    if(!isFirstLoop)
        insertQuery += ","
    insertQuery += word;
    isFirstLoop = false;        
}
insertQuery += ")";
SqlDataSource.InsertCommand = insertQuery;
```

NOTE: this is very open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), so keep that in mind (do you trust your incoming source). There are ways to clean the data, but ultimately, I suggest some of the methods listed below

Alternatives:

- Use a stored procedure over direct TSQL. Then you can map your data to SQLParameters, which (I believe) are built to scrub the data to protect against SQL Injection
- Use a very basic ORM and/or LINQ so that you can work with objects directly. Then you only need to read the data into a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)
- I am sure there are other ways, however for some reason I am drawing a blank. I think that is because these are the most used alternatives :)

Comment: Thank you very much Justin, this did the trick for me, I'm seeing my parsed data in the right columns of my table. The data I am receiving is in fact coming in the same order as my columns and its a trusted source.  However, I'm curious about doing this calling a stored procedure. Would it make a difference? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Using a stored procedure would protect you more against SQL injection for one, and it would start to declutter your code (code should look like code, and SQL should look like SQL. The closer you can get to that separation, the better IMO). Also, by using stored procedures you could shut your database down so that it does not allow direct SQL. This will allow for better security control (you can allow users/roles access to only certain sprocs), instead of just allowing any SQL into the system